# Using Ajax #! for Google but site is not being crawled any more

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, ajax, web-crawlers

Our pages used to be formulated using the `?` string but since we changed to AJAX loading we now use `#!`, for example:

- Old link: `/post.php?idPost=5326`
- New link: `/post.php#!idPost=5326`

The snapshot you can get it by `adding _escaped_fragment_=` after the `?`.

*All have the same content,  what has happened to the site since we changed the linking system?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though [hashbangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) `#!` are still supported, [Google suggests](http://youtu.be/yiAF9VdvRPw) steering away from using them and just use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the URL. Libraries like [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) make it easy to do so.

This basically removes your problem altogether, there's no need to set up urls with `_escaped_fragment_` when using the History API

Answer (score 1):

According do [Google's Guide](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) the url  `/post.php#!idPost=5326` would get crawled at `/post.php?_escaped_fragment_=idPost=5326`. 
Your server would have to respond to that URL the same way that it used to respond to `/post.php?idPost=5326`.

You should then use a 301 redirect from `/post.php?idPost=5326` to `/post.php#!idPost=5326`.

Answer (score -1):

Read this to solve your issue:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: When answering, please provide more than a link.  For example, please quote relevant parts of the linked document or explain the answer in your own words.